# Terminal error output RE: editing .conf file in Xbuntu [owned by uid 1000 istead of 0]

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, sudo, root, konsole

Was curious as to the terminal error output from running `sudo Kate`. I read in a forum that directed me to open my notepad using `gksudo`. Realizing that this had not been installed I just went ahead and tried to open my notepad editor with `sudo` and edit the `.conf` file (which worked, by that I mean it saved the new `.conf` file without root access error, but left me with *"lines of unknown errors"*). I have no problem running `sudo` on my Raspberry PI to open and edit text files using `nano`.

What caused the error lines, and how to fix them if easily answered?

```
skratch@Slick:~$ sudo kate
[sudo] password for skratch: 
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
kdeinit4: Shutting down running client.
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Error: "/tmp/ksocket-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/tmp/kde-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
kbuildsycoca4 running...
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::resourceScoreUpdated(QString, QString, QString, double) to NepomukPlugin::resourceScoreUpdated(QString, QString, QString, double)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::recentStatsDeleted(QString, int, QString) to NepomukPlugin::deleteRecentStats(QString, int, QString)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::earlierStatsDeleted(QString, int) to NepomukPlugin::deleteEarlierStats(QString, int)
QDBusConnection: name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel' had owner '' but we thought it was ':1.8'
Error: "/tmp/kde-skratch" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Uid 1000 is you. Uid 0 is root. Take a loot at output of `ls -l /var/tmp` . There's some folders that you have ownership of, and some that root owns. If you're not owner of a file and permissions are `drwx------`, you can't open it, simple as that. When you called kate with root privileges, kate needed to access folders that are owned by you, but the program was executed from root's perspective. Hence the errors

Comment: Just curious can a file/folder be owned by myself and root? Also, after the drwx------ there are numbers (two assigned a 2 [lightdm & root] and one assigned a 6 [skratch {me}]for the 3 folders listed). Does this mean lightdm owns one, root the other and me the last of the three? Only reason I ask and again referring back to the RPi and there being no errors is because I wanted to attempt to fix the issue. Is this an issue or can this be fixed, or is this completely normal? Also is the RPi and nano giving no issues possibly because the permissions were granted differently/correctly? Thank u!

Comment: Well nano doesn't need those folders , it operates directly on whatever file you edit. Also in ls -l two names , like root root, refer to owner and the group to which the file belongs.  Add the output of ls -l /var/tmp and I will try to explain it tomorrow or someone else can ; it's late at my place and I am heading to bed right now